# User Role Relation lost in Grails Spring Security Application

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm facing a weird issue in my grails 2.5.5 application with spring-security-core:2.0-RC6 and spring-security-oauth2-provider:2.0-RC5. Recently, an admin user lost his role and he wasn't able to login to the system. I tried to debug my application but wasn't able to find the reason for this.

Here is my UserRole domain class:

```
SysUser user
Role role
```

With a regular user class generated from spring security. We faced this issue also with User Location relationship. It is many to many relationship and suddenly this relation get discarded between random users and locations.

```
Location
static hasMany = [locEmployees: User]
Collection locEmployees=[]
```

and the User class

```
static hasMany =[locations:Location]
static belongsTo = Location
```

Has anyone faced this type of issues? Any ideas how can I solve it?

Comment: In the database the relationship still exists?

Comment: @SérgioMichels No it is not

Comment: @SérgioMichels Do you have any idea why did this  happen?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you shouldn't be using an RC - the 2.0.0 release has been available for over a year. The more likely issue is defining the has-many with `Collection`. By default the collection type is `Set` but can also be `List`; specifying `Collection` makes Hibernate create a 'bag' which I showed at http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1029 to be no better than and sometimes worse than using a `Set` or `List`.

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith do you mean that I need to get the whole collection of objects when I do an update operation if I'm using a Collection? What if the hasMany relationship has thousands of objects this may cause the app to crash.

Comment: I said nothing about usage, only about the configuration

Comment: @BurtBeckwith this was just a question. By the way, if you notice the UserRole domain class there is no Collection type there. I use the default implementation, however the relation is lost also.